# When is there "data loss" when converting from BigDecimal to Double in Java

Tags: java, string, double, converters, bigdecimal

I know there are "precision issues" when converting BigDecimal values to Double in Java. When is there "data loss" when simply converting from BigDecimal to Double using BigDecimal.doubleValue()? For example, if I convert 1.1 from BigDecimal to Double and print it out, it prints "1.1" which I would consider to have no data loss (the BigDecimal was 1.1 and the printed value was 1.1). When are the cases these two values would not be the same when simply converting from BigDecimal to Double in this way?

Comment: If you choose a higher precision when printing, you‘ll see that the double is very close to, but not exactly 1.1, because binary floating point cannot exactly represent 1.1, while BigDecimal can. So there is a loss of precision. The fact that a double only has a lmited nunber of bits, while a BigDecimal an almost unlimited nunber should also be a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BigDecimal` has as much precision as you like. A `double` has 53 bits of binary precision, which is ~15.9 decimal digits. So any time your `BigDecimal` has > 16 significant digits you are in for loss of precision when converting to `double`.

[This is in reference to integer values. The situation with fractions is considerably more complex, but the fact remains that `BigDecimal` has unlimited precision where `double` does not.]

Also a `double` has minimum and maximum values, given by `Double.MIN_VALUE/MAX_VALUE`. `BigDecimal` has neither.

Comment: Are there other cases other than this also?

Comment: Precision and range. There's nothing more to it.